# Call a function if userinteraction is nil for 3 seconds

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, ios5

Guys i need to call a function in such a view that if there is no user interaction for three seconds the function should be called
what should i do?

Can any one pls give a logic or link which help this?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My recommendation is to override - (void)touchesBegan: withEvent: on that view.

When you receive a touch event, set a timer, and make its time 3 seconds. If you receive a touch and there is a timer, change its fire date to be 3 seconds after the touch time. When the timer fires, call the function, and set the timer to nil.

You can play with the movement, removals and cancellation methods to make your timer fire correctly and at the right time for the activity required.

Answer (score -1):

Use NSTimer as:-

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{ 
 UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
 CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
 if ([touch view] == self.view) 
  {
    NSTimer *updateTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3 target:self selector:@selector(updateTime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
  }
}

-(void)updateTime
{
NSLog(@"....Update Function Called....");
[self functionName];
}
```

Use this for calling function.Check it Hope it helps.Thanks :)

Comment: Note that this is certainly not a good idea from a performance perspective: You are firing a timer 3 times more often than required, and you are firing it even when no user interaction occurs EVEN IF the view is not onscreen. View Did Load is no judge for when the view actually came onscreen. Also note that this code is no-longer tied to the view. The view is not independently aware. This relies on the controller which isn't necessarily the best model. Overall seems a very hacked way to do it.

Comment: Your method when touchesBegan should also check for an existent timer. If one exists, push it back rather than just creating a new one. This ensures that the method does not get called until AFTER it occurs.

Note that this does not take into consideration touches moving as well, which would also need to delay the timer as well.